# OrthographicTrackballControls vs. TrackballControls

Tags: three.js

I've implemented a scene where I use both Orthographic and Perspective cameras, and their respective trackball controls. But it feels like they're out of sync.

Sometimes the results of switching between them are as expected, while other times the output is completely wrong.

In the image below, I rotated the model in perspective mode, took a snapshot, then checked the box to put it in ortho mode, and took a second snapshot. There was no other manipulation done to the scene between switching cameras.

Here is is working as expected after a slight rotation in perspective mode:
[image: Working example]

And here it is after some random rotations while in perspective mode:
[image: Broken example]

(I know I have zooming issues as well--I'm working on that one.)

Of course, I'm open to the idea that *I'm* the one doing something completely wrong--it has been ages since I've worked with Ortho cameras, so I might be forgetting some concepts, but the fact that it works *sometimes* makes me think I'm at least on the right track, and probably just need a nudge in the right direction.

I've tried the CombinedCamera, but it didn't behave well with the OrthographicTrackballControl.

Any input or suggestions are appreciated. (r68 & r69)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheJim01/rckanx2L/103/

```
var hostDiv, scene, renderer, oCamera, pCamera, root, oControls, pControls, ctrl, light, shape, o;

var WIDTH = 500,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    FOV = 28,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 60;

function init() {
    o = false;
    
    hostDiv = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(hostDiv);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserverDrawingBuffer: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    hostDiv.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
    pCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR );
    oCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( 0, 0, 0, 0, NEAR, FAR );
    
    pCamera.position.z = 50;
    oCamera.position.z = 10;
    
    height = Math.tan(pCamera.fov / 2) * 2 * pCamera.near;
    width = height * pCamera.aspect;
    
    oCamera.left = width / -2;
    oCamera.right = width / 2;
    oCamera.top = height / 2;
    oCamera.bottom = height / -2;
    
    pControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(pCamera, renderer.domElement);
    oControls = new THREE.OrthographicTrackballControls(oCamera, renderer.domElement);

    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(pCamera);
    scene.add(oCamera);
    scene.add(light);
    
    scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.5));
    
    var cube = colorCube(5);
    scene.add(cube);
    
    pControls.target.copy(cube.position);
    
    animate();
}

function animate() {
   
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    if(o) {
        light.position.copy(oCamera.position);
        renderer.render(scene, oCamera);
    }
    else {
        light.position.copy(pCamera.position);
        renderer.render(scene, pCamera);
    }
    
    oControls.update();
    pControls.update();
}

function change(e) {
    o = e.checked;
}

function colorCube(scale){
    var geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    
    var positions = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var normals = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var colors = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var indices = new Uint16Array( 36 );
    
    var face = 0, idx = 0, vert = 0;
    var x = 0, r = 0, y = 1, g = 1, z = 2, b = 2;
    
    // front face (RED)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // back face (BLUE)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // right face (GREEN)
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // left face (MAGENTA)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // top face (CYAN)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // bottom face (YELLOW)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    geo.addAttribute( 'index', new THREE.BufferAttribute( indices, 1 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
    
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xffffff,
                    ambient: 0xffffff,
                    specular: 0xffffff,
                    shininess: 50,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
                } );    
    
    var msh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    msh.scale.multiplyScalar(scale);
    
    return msh;
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the two controls are indeed out of sync. When I added an observation camera, and camera helpers, I was able to watch their location vectors diverge almost immediately.

Whether that's by design or not, I don't know. Regardless, I was able to get it working for my purposes in the jsfiddle below.

I gave up trying to sync the controls and now rely only on the perspective camera control. I then update the ortho camera based on the orientation of the perspective camera, and vice versa.

I'm not going to accept this answer right away, as there may be better solutions out there.

**UPDATE:**
I finally got both cameras to sync up together. There must be a better way of doing this, so I'll leave this answer open for a few days.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheJim01/jkbwk4xn/76/

```
// P/O Camera Tester

var hostDiv, scene, renderer, light, o;
var pCamera, oCamera, watchCamera;
var pControls, oControls;
var pHelper, oHelper;

var WIDTH = 600,
    HEIGHT = 300,
    FOV = 28,
    NEAR = 40,
    FAR = 60;

var oBackup, dist = 0;
function render() {
    oBackup = oCamera.clone();
    
    light.position.copy(pControls.object.position);
    
    renderer.clear();
    
    renderer.setViewport(0, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT);
    
    if(o) {
        renderer.render(scene, oCamera);
    }
    else {
        renderer.render(scene, pCamera);
    }
    
    pControls.update();
    oControls.update();
    
    if(o) {
        // zoom
        if(oBackup.top !== oCamera.top ||
           oBackup.right !== oCamera.right ||
           oBackup.bottom !== oCamera.bottom ||
           oBackup.left !== oCamera.left) {
            oCamera.position.copy(pCamera.position);
        }
        pCamera.position.copy(oCamera.position);
        pCamera.up.copy(oCamera.up);
        pCamera.lookAt(oControls.target);
        pControls.target.copy(oControls.target);
    }
    else {
        oCamera.position.copy(pCamera.position);
        oCamera.up.copy(pCamera.up);
        oCamera.lookAt(pControls.target);
        oControls.target.copy(pControls.target);
    }
    if(pCamera.up.x === undefined) debugger;
    if(oCamera.up.x === undefined) debugger;
    
    dist = pCamera.position.distanceTo(pControls.target);
    
    pCamera.near = dist - 10;
    pCamera.far = dist + 10;
    oCamera.near = dist - 10;
    oCamera.far = dist + 10;
    
    pCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    oCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    
    pHelper.update();
    oHelper.update();
    
    renderer.setViewport(WIDTH/2, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT);
    renderer.render(scene, watchCamera);
    
    oBackup = null;
}

function animate() {
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
    render();
}

function init() {
    o = false;
    
    hostDiv = document.createElement('div');
    hostDiv.style.position = 'relative';
    hostDiv.style.top = '0';
    hostDiv.style.left = '0';
    document.body.appendChild(hostDiv);
    
    var moveDiv = document.createElement('div');
    moveDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    moveDiv.style.top = '0';
    moveDiv.style.left = '0';
    moveDiv.style.width = (WIDTH/2).toString() + 'px';
    moveDiv.style.height = (HEIGHT).toString() + 'px';
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    watchCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 14, 0.5 * WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 1000 );
    watchCamera.position.x = 200;
    watchCamera.position.y = 200;
    watchCamera.position.z = 200;
    watchCamera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    
    pCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, 0.5* WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR );
    oCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -12, 12, 12, -12, NEAR, FAR );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserverDrawingBuffer: true });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
    hostDiv.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    hostDiv.appendChild(moveDiv);
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    
    pCamera.position.z = 50;
    oCamera.position.z = 50;
    
    pControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(pCamera, moveDiv);
    oControls = new THREE.OrthographicTrackballControls(oCamera, moveDiv);
    
    pControls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    oControls.target.set(0, 0, 0);

    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1., Infinity);
    var hemi = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.5);
    
    var cube = colorCube(5);
    
    scene.add(pCamera);
    scene.add(oCamera);
    scene.add(watchCamera);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(hemi);
    scene.add(cube);
    
    var debug = true;
    if(debug) {
        pHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( pCamera );
        scene.add( pHelper );
        oHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( oCamera );    
        scene.add( oHelper );
        
        var sphereSize = 1;
        var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light, sphereSize );
        scene.add( pointLightHelper );
        
        var arrowXp = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0x00ff00);
        scene.add(arrowXp);
        
        var arrowXn = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0xff00ff);
        scene.add(arrowXn);
        
        var arrowYp = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0x00ffff);
        scene.add(arrowYp);
        
        var arrowYn = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0xffff00);
        scene.add(arrowYn);
        
        var arrowZp = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0xff0000);
        scene.add(arrowZp);
        
        var arrowZn = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            10,
            0x0000ff);
        scene.add(arrowZn);
    }
    
    animate();
}

function change(e) {
    o = e.checked;
}

function colorCube(scale){
    var geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    
    var positions = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var normals = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var colors = new Float32Array( 72 );
    var indices = new Uint16Array( 36 );
    
    var face = 0, idx = 0, vert = 0;
    var x = 0, r = 0, y = 1, g = 1, z = 2, b = 2;
    
    // front face (RED)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // back face (BLUE)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = -1.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // right face (GREEN)
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // left face (MAGENTA)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = -1.; normals[vert + y] = 0.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 0.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // top face (CYAN)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = 0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = 1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 0.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 1.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    // bottom face (YELLOW)
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = -0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = 0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    positions[vert + x] = -0.5; positions[vert + y] = -0.5; positions[vert + z] = 0.5;
    normals[vert + x] = 0.; normals[vert + y] = -1.; normals[vert + z] = 0.;
    colors[vert + r] = 1.; colors[vert + g] = 1.; colors[vert + b] = 0.;
    vert += 3;
    
    indices[idx + 0] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 1] = (face * 4) + 1; indices[idx + 2] = (face * 4) + 2;
    indices[idx + 3] = (face * 4) + 0; indices[idx + 4] = (face * 4) + 2; indices[idx + 5] = (face * 4) + 3;
    idx += 6;
    ++face;
    
    geo.addAttribute( 'index', new THREE.BufferAttribute( indices, 1 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
    geo.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
    
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xffffff,
                    ambient: 0xffffff,
                    specular: 0xffffff,
                    shininess: 50,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
                } );    
    
    var msh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    msh.scale.multiplyScalar(scale);
    
    return msh;
}

init();
```

Comment: The camera is still a little buggy, so I'm tempted to say that putting them into a camera rig is a better option than constantly copying position/orientation back and forth. One would still need to calculate frustum changes, but that's to be expected.